# Export custom tools from Visual Studio Toolbox

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a VS project with several custom components:

[image: Text]

These components are written in .vb classes:

[image: Text]

The problem is that they have a lot of external references and I was not able to import them correctly in another project.

Is there a quick way to do it?

Comment: You might want to look into creating one or more NuGet packages, so you can build the dependencies into them. I think that that might require that the dependencies are available as NuGet packages too though. Yours may or may not be, depending on what they are.

Comment: Note that you can have a project generate a NuGet package on build, so you can look into the project properties for that. There are also standalone tools that will generate them and I'm guessing it can be done at the commandline to, although I've never tried.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider generating a Nuget package from a project that contains a custom component, so that when you use the Nuget package, the package as its dependencies can be installed along with it.

Check [Quickstart: Create and publish a NuGet package using Visual Studio (Windows only)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli)